# Can I make cpp not to output space line on #pragma?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

I'm writing a turing machine in C preprocessor with `#pragma push_macro` and `#pragma pop_macro`. I want to make it directly output the result when the preprocessing is done, rather than output a print-only program that still need run to get result.

Part of the source code:

```
// main.c
int printf(char*, ...);
int main() {
    #define CODEFILE "command.c"
    #include "turing.h"
    #undef CODEFILE
}
// turing.h
#ifndef PARSE
#define PARSE(x) x
#pragma push_macro("PARSE")
#undef PARSE
#pragma pop_macro("PARSE")
#ifndef PARSE
#error push_macro/pop_macro not supported!
#else
#define GET03(x,y,z) x
#define GET13(x,y,z) y
#define GET23(x,y,z) z
#define GETN(n,l) PARSE(GET##n l)
#define COMMAND GETN(03, MOVE)
#define TNEXT GETN(13, MOVE)
#define FNEXT GETN(23, MOVE)
#define LEFT SPECIAL(1)
#define RIGHT SPECIAL(2)
#define NOP SPECIAL(3)
#define WARN SPECIAL(4)
#define HALT SPECIAL(5)
#define DEPTH 0
#pragma push_macro("DEPTH")
#undef DEPTH
#define DEPTH 1
#endif
#endif
#
#
#ifdef PARSE
#define STATUS 0
#define PTRL 0
#define PTR 0
#
#include "infloop.h"
#
#include "clrmemlp.h"
#
#pragma pop_macro("DEPTH")
#undef FINISHED
#undef STATUS
#undef PTRL
#undef PTR
#
#endif
```

Running `cpp main.c` would get: (some lines contain spaces at the end)

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "main.c"
int printf(char*, ...);
int main() {

# 1 "turing.h" 1





# 22 "turing.h"

# 34 "turing.h"
# 1 "infloop.h" 1

...
```

The line numbers are annoying here. Then I see in the `--help` document:

```
  -P                          Do not generate #line directives
```

Using this flag I can get

```
int printf(char*, ...);
int main() {








printf ("x = %d, ", 1);


...
```

However there are still a large amount of empty lines. It seems they come from `#pragma`, and I also tested:

```
1
#pragma push_macro("x")
2
#define x 3
3
#undef x
4
#include "nul"
5
```

and the result is

```
1

2
3
4
5
```

So I'm pretty sure the empty lines come from `#pragma`. Is there any way to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right the `#pragma` directive expands to a new line. Seems like `gcc` has no options to control this behavior.

A minimal example would be:

```
// turing.h
#pragma push_macro("Test")

// main.c
int main() {
#include "turing.h"
}
```

The output is:

```
int main() {

}
```

Also take a look, that `#pragma` directive which compiler can't understand just expands as it.

Comment: Tested and find that even if some empty lines exist, they'll be removed; yet `#pragma` leaves 7+spaces between `#` and `pragma` spaces making them unremovble

Comment: I guess it depends on the content `infloop.h`  and `clrmemlp.h`.

Comment: what depends on the content `infloop.h` and `clrmemlp.h`?

Answer (score 0):

You could always feed the output through a filter:

```
gcc -E -P main.c | grep '[^ ]'
```

The `grep` selects all lines which have some character which is not a space; in other words, it removes all empty lines and lines consisting only of spaces. With GNU grep, you could use the pattern `\S`, which would also ignore lines containing only spaces and tabs.